# Use global npm package instead of installing it again

Tags: javascript, docker, npm

Is there any way to use the package installed globally instead of install the same when we run `npm i`.
I have the following context:
I've created a docker image with one package already installed (install statement in the Dockerfile). When I run the container with the volumen which has the javascript project and I run `npm i` it seems the package is installed again.

Could it be possible use the global package instead of instal it again?

Comment: I'd suggest listing _all_ of your dependencies in the `package.json` file.  In a Docker context, don't `RUN npm install individual-package`, and more generally, don't expect your dependencies to be installed globally.  (And don't store your code or library trees in volumes, they should be built into the image.)

Comment: Due to business necessity, there is one package that is needed to be installed once the image is created, so the steps should: 1. Create an image with the step to install a package `RUN npm i -g install package_example`. 2. Once the image is created, log in and run `npm i` inside container.  3. The package_example is taken from global cache instead of install again.

Comment: As i told you, once the image is created you can use it as new base image and reinstall from there what ever you need.  Than you start your code with a CMD which executes your code. I really dont understand how you want install new npm packages in a running container. Or you do something like CMD ['sleep','99999']. Login install the modules , than you start the app. But this is really not to recommand. What if your container crashs? You want to login and execute each time again and again manually what you described?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to install again during the docker build the node_modules, you can create a base image with your node_modules.

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*  ./
RUN  npm install
```

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

You can tag and push it to registry (dockerhub)
Or use it locally as your new base image.

```
FROM myimage
WORKDIR /usr/src/app #Here are now already your node_modules
COPY . .  # copy your code inside the image, or map the folder if you are in 
          # development

RUN npm run build # if you need a build
CMD ["mycommand","myargument"]
```

Note this quick, but you need to rebuild your base image if you add or update the node modules.

Consider also to use npm ci instead of npm install. In this way you keep same versions of your node modules each time you reinstall them.

Take care of security issues of the node modules as well of your base images.

run `docker scan myimage`, periodically to get information of your node_modules or base images need updates.

During development, it is absolutly fine to map your code folders with the docker image. While developing is not even necessary to copy your code in the image. Just map it in your WORKDIR.

Comment: Probably I don't explain very well. Here is my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799153/use-global-npm-package-instead-of-installing-it-again#comment132028912_74799153

Answer (score 0):

After researching it seems the follow code solves my problem

```
WORKDIR /dir

RUN npm install package
RUN npm cache add package
RUN rm -rf *

WORKDIR /
```